# TextBelt free SMS texting API doesn't work

Tags: linux, api, terminal, automation, sms

I recently used the free testing API from textBelt to try sending the SMS, i was thinking to embed this on a small application that i am building. It looks like its not working anymore or at least not in my machine or I don't know however it returns true on my terminal. Anyone have any idea on this.

```
curl http://textbelt.com/text -d number=2563567890 -d "message=text goes here"
```

Comment: Can you verify that you are using POST? That's how the textbelt.com website has its example.

Comment: I tried with that as well. It returns me  "success": true but i never get the sms. I have tried with multiple other numbers too but no luck.

Comment: Have you confirmed that you cell carrier is one of the supported ones? Also, if the number was ported from another carrier it may cause some issues.

Comment: Humm... I haven't contacted them but I had tried like 10 different phone numbers from all careers. It's just strange. Does it work for you ?

Comment: Same is with me too. textbelt has not delivered SMS on my mobile as well,  although got `success` in response.

Comment: Have you tried again since? It may have been a temporary outage, or carriers blocking textbelt at the time (and the developer had to make changes, time and time again). It works for me today.

Answer (score 2):

I have used this service in the past and I noticed today that text messages sent were not received.  Looking into this a bit further it seems something happened due to folks using this service to spam... and it's not working at present.   Not sure what the future holds...
See: [issue listed on textbelt](https://github.com/typpo/textbelt/issues/76)

Looking for a solution still....

Joel Parke

Comment: Textbelt has gone through "outages" or what can be considered carriers blocking textbelt at times due to heavy usage & spamming (and the developer had to make changes, time and time again). It works for me today.

Comment: Part of that problem is because textbelt mass emails/texts your message to all carriers hoping one of them is valid, hence much more likely to be treated as spam, than a more targeted service like http://www.watacrackaz.com/autosms/api.php, which (is free and) requires specifying the carrier. Specifying carrier option was added to textbelt recently, but I don't think it's widely publicized. See https://github.com/typpo/textbelt/pull/57

Answer (score 0):

2-563-567-890 doesn't look like a valid US phone number, so I would double-check that.  There is also an international endpoint, `/intl`, but it tends to be less reliable.

Comment: Lets suppose thats a valid US phone no, still its not working.